# Make accordion close once click occurs anywhere on the page

Tags: jquery

I have an small div that once revealed shows important data that needs to stay hidden from view unless otherwise chosen.

I'm having trouble getting it to work how I need.

Essentially this code slides out that div when the button is double clicked. However, if the div is open I would like to close it after 5 seconds or if another click takes place anywhere on the page. I tried playing around but cannot get it to work at all.

```
$( "#button" ).dblclick(function() {
   $( "#item" ).toggle("accordion");
});
```

The problem I run into is that the additional jquery I add doesn't check to see if the div is open so the actions are just overlapping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this...

```
$( "#button" ).on( 'click', function() {
    $( "#item" ).toggle('accordion');
    var autoClose = setTimeout( function() { $( "#item" ).toggle('accordion'); $( window ).unbind( 'mousedown' ); } , 5000);

    $( window ).on( 'mousedown', function( event ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $( "#item" ).toggle('accordion');
        $( window ).unbind( 'mousedown' );
        clearTimeout(autoClose)
    });
});
```

Here's a fiddle... https://jsfiddle.net/zxf9jsp2/

Comment: Awesome! Exactly what I needed. Thanks a ton!